# If statement not executing during ActionPerformed event

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Trying to write a Swing GUI. When clicking a button, I want to test if the other button has already been clicked. If it has, then execute the statements in the "if" statements. But it looks like the "if" statements never execute?

```
private void radSingleBurgerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(radDoubleBurger.isSelected()){
        newItemPrice = Double.parseDouble(lblItemPrice.getText());
        newItemPrice -= doublePrice;
        lblTest.setText(String.valueOf(newItemPrice));//test to see if working
    }
    lblItemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(newItemPrice += singlePrice));
}                                               

private void radDoubleBurgerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     if(radSingleBurger.isSelected()){
        newItemPrice = Double.parseDouble(lblItemPrice.getText());
        newItemPrice -= singlePrice;
        lblTest.setText(String.valueOf(newItemPrice));//test to see if working
    }
    lblItemPrice.setText(String.valueOf(newItemPrice += doublePrice));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking a `JButton` does not make it (permanently) selected. Clicking is only a temporary action.

Maybe you want to use a `JToggleButton`. This allows you to click a button to make it selected and then click it again to make it unselected.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information.

Or if you just want to know if the user has clicked on a regular `JButton`, then you will need to maintain a Boolean variable yourself that you update in the ActionListener of the button.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really tired from staring at the screen trying to figure this out. I added a boolean check variable and now it works. I tried to add it to the listener but the NetBeans IDE won't let me edit them???

Comment: @CryHavoc_Mike, I don't use an IDE to generate code, so I can't help there. I would rather write the code myself and then I am in full control. Also, code generated by an IDE will not be maintainable if you ever switch to a different IDE. Just use the IDE to help compile and debug, organize your classes etc.